# QGIS: Exported layer values differ from the underlying raster layer they were exported from

Tags: qgis, export, gdal-merge

I´m trying to merge multiple raster layers (partial overlap) and then export them into a single layer for my required area of interest (AOI). When i use the raster merge (gdal_merge) option it merges all the rasters into one raster, in areas where there is overlap values from the last image is used(https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html), which i understand. The merged raster has only 4 bands (R, G, B and NIR) the same as the original rasters.

But when i try to export this image for my AOI using extents i get slightly different raster values in some areas. Why is this happening? Shouldn´t the raster values be exactly the same?

I export it in Raw data output mode, GeoTIFF format, with a custom extent and no compression. Let me know if anything is unclear.

[image: Qdal_merge and then export]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven´t found out why this happens. But instead of exporting, clipping the original image with a mask layer (which has the extents of my required AOI) seems to produce the desired output.